# How to make a GridView component with DateTimePicker using Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I need to build a GridView component which contains a DateTime picker.How can i do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007010/how-to-create-a-reusable-grid-view-component-like-date-time-picker-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<asp:TemplateField>` to set control what you want as column.

Comment: No,i need a gridview component with a datetimepicker